# Create a WordPress installation Zip with theme and plugins installed

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to prepare a customized WordPress installation zip file which will include a custom default theme and a number of other plugins already installed?

If it is, I would appreciate a hint in the right direction since I've been banging my head against the wall on this for 2 days now :)

Thanks!

Comment: You may customize WordPress at your local machine and then upload it to your server.

Comment: so just install it, add plugins, theme, compress it, then export and import DB?

Comment: You don't need data base. Just extract the required themes and plugins to the corresponding directories. Upload and activate theme and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution is to just ship your theme with a list of plugins that it requires, which in turn will allow you to download and activate them all with a click. This means that the action would be done automatically.

To be able to require plugins to be downloaded and installed programatically, check out this compact library - [TGM Plugin Activation](https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Plugin-Activation).

It allows you to specify plugins that should be installed from Wordpress official respository, as well as your own local copies, which can ship with your theme's zip file.